# Getting the attribute of a parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the id of a table using a table row. While I am in a loop:

```
$(this).parent.attr('id');
```

However I am getting an error. Is my syntax right?

Thanks.

EDIT:

```
<table id="21-rawTable" border="1"><tbody><tr class="even notSelected eClr" name="0" id="beaf-32;Developmental-Stage_Embryo-0-12h;ChIP-chip;Rep-1;input;Dmel_r54;modENCODE_21;BEAF_Input_0.CEL" title="/modencode/modencode-dcc/symbolic_links/Dmel_r5.4/Non-TF-Chromatin-binding-factor/ChIP-chip/raw-arrayfile_CEL/beaf-32/Embryo 0-12h/" style="cursor:pointer;" "="" onclick="selected('beaf-32;Developmental-Stage_Embryo-0-12h;ChIP-chip;Rep-1;input;Dmel_r54;modENCODE_21;BEAF_Input_0.CEL','[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]')"><td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="beaf-32;Developmental-Stage_Embryo-0-12h;ChIP-chip;Rep-1;input;Dmel_r54;modENCODE_21;BEAF_Input_0.CELcheckBox" checked=""></td><td>beaf-32;Developmental-Stage_Embryo-0-12h;ChIP-chip;Rep-1;input;Dmel_r54;modENCODE_21;BEAF_Input_0.CEL</td><td>0 bytes</td></tr><!-- table--></tbody></table>
```

Using this code to get the id of the table which in this case is "21-rawTable"

```
$(".selected").each(function () {
var parentname = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        alert (parentname);
});
```

I resolved the issue. I think it was giving me the direct parent. Instead I had to do a search for the closest ancestor like such:

```
var parentname = ($(this).closest('table')).attr('id');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the error you're receiving as well as more of the context (html, enclosing loop, etc)?  You can share the details using this site: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @falcata , cleanup your html , move the inline code to jquery..so that it will be easy to debug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`parent`*<sup>[[API Ref](http://api.jquery.com/parent)]</sup>* is a method, so you should call it like this:

```
$(this).parent().attr('id');
```

Comment: I'm getting an undefined with this.

Comment: Please edit your question then to provide some context as to where you are using this line of code.

Comment: Included brackets around the call to parent(), still getting an undefined.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to include the parentheses on the call to the `parent()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any tags with `class='selected'` in your sample HTML. However:

- the parent of the checkbox is the TD.
- the parent of the TD is the TR.
- the parent of the TR is the TBODY.
- the parent of the TBODY is the TABLE.

You can use `.closest(selector)` to get the table ancestor from anywhere inside of it, though:

`$(this).closest('table').attr('id');`

http://api.jquery.com/closest/